Set PlayerName/NickName in Photon Fusion
In the latest version of Photon Fusion, I'm encountering difficulty setting the player's nickname or username. It seems that the NickName property, which was previously used for this purpose, has been removed. Can anyone provide guidance on how to set the player's username in Photon Fusion now? I've checked the documentation and couldn't find any alternative method. Any help would be appreciated.
I tried using the NickName property in Photon Fusion to set the player's username, but it seems to have been removed in the latest version. I expected that setting this property would display the player's username in the game. However, since it's no longer available, I'm unsure how to proceed. Any suggestions on how to set the player's username now would be helpful. Thanks!

The most common way to do this type of thing is to have a NetworkObject for each player that contains the nickname as a NetworkString:
public class PlayerData : NetworkBehaviour {
   [Networked] NetworkString<_16> NickName { get; set; }

   public override void Spawned() {
       // If in Host/Server mode:
       if (HasInputAuthority) {
           Rpc_SetNickname(...);
       }
       Runner.SetPlayerObject(InputAuthority, Object);

       // If in Shared mode
       if (HasStateAuthority) {
           NickName = ...;
       }
       Runner.SetPlayerObject(StateAuthority, Object);
    }

    // Only required in host/server mode.
    [Rpc(RpcSources.InputAuthority, RpcTargets.StateAuthority)]
    public void Rpc_SetNickname(string nickname) {
        NickName = nickname;
    }
}

Then you can do
PlayerRef player = ...;
Runner.GetPlayerObject(player).GetComponent<PlayerData>().NickName;

to get a specific player's username.
